# get OpenCV Mat variables of rgb and depth information from pcl openni grabber

Tags: opencv, kinect, openni, point-cloud-library

I'm now using pcl openni grabber to get point cloud from kinect cameras. But I also want to get OpenCV Mat variables for the rgb and depth information.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it a video streaming or an image from a single point cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found pcl has its own openni2 wrapper to get the color and depth image directly. We can write a callback function like:

```
void PclProcessor::image_cb1_ (const boost::shared_ptr<pcl::io::Image>& rgb1, const boost::shared_ptr<pcl::io::DepthImage>& depth1, float reciprocalFocalLength)
{
    if (refreshK1)
    {
        C1 = Mat(rgb1->getHeight(), rgb1->getWidth(), CV_8UC3);
        rgb1->fillRGB(C1.cols,C1.rows,C1.data,C1.step);
        cvtColor(C1, C1, CV_RGB2BGR);

        D1 = Mat(depth1->getHeight(), depth1->getWidth(), CV_32F);
        depth1->fillDepthImage(D1.cols, D1.rows,(float *)D1.data,D1.step);

        refreshK1 = false;
    }
    imshow("camera 1 color",C1);
    imshow("camera 1 depth",D1);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

In this case, I can get the color image right. However, the depth image does not look right.

[image: color image]
[image: depth image]

Comment: the depth image is in 16bit value (unsigned int) and they have values in milimiters. Just use the normalize function of OpenCV to display it (do not save this image, save the raw one). `cv::normalize(D1, nice_output , 0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);` should do the work ;)